# Visual Studio won't show added files in the solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visualgdb

### Why would VS2019 (with VisualGdb) refuse to show added files the solution explorer?

I found some workaround, i will post as an answer. But i'm still quite interested in the explanation of the underlying problem.

---

Additional info: opening the project file (.vcxproj) shows that the files are actually added to the project, only they are "invisible" in the project explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if this issue is VS-related or VisualGDB-related, or even layer-8-related, but hopefully this answer will help some people anyway.

So after trying many things not leading to success, i found this **workaround**:

In the project file (.vcxproj), i actually found entries for theses "invisible" files, and after deleting them and re-opening VS, i added these files again in the soluton explorer. Only this time, they correctly showed up in the solution explorer.

Weird: a compare tool showed not the slightest change in the project file, so there got to be some underlying issue.